# Cover HTML Navbar in CSS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of HTML elements that create a Dialogue Box that show a loading spinner. It also has a semi-opaque background that fills the page. It fills up the whole page except the navbar. How could I cover up the navbar as well in CSS? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGbz8.png)

Here is my CSS for the background:

```
.dialog {

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 270px;
  min-height: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 999;
}

#loadingDialog {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:999;
}
```

and the corrisponding HTML:

```
    <div id="loadingDialog" ng-class="loadClass">
        <div class="dialog">
          <div class="page">
            <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;opacity:0.6;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg"></i> Loading...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Navbar CSS:

```
.navigation-bar {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  height: 44px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Post your `Html` and `Css` or make a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a div that stays above all the others you can use the following code:

```
body {position: relative;}

.infront {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

As css, and the following html code after the opening `<body>`-tag:

```
<div class="infront"><!-- your content --></div>
```

My guess is, that your nav bar stays white, because you have nested the overlaying loading box somehow in your content area, or positioned your nav bar with `position: absolute` which makes it stay in front of the other divs. To avoid this I have added `z-index: 999;` which creates kind of a depth of field and lets the div with the higher z-index stay above the others.

If you need more precise help it's always helpful to post the code snippets you are using as well! For further information feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Marian.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I have edited my question with my CSS and HTML, but all these properties were already set accordingly.

Comment: hi @breadedturtle. Its good that you have added your CSS and HTML, but the loading screen does not seem to be the problem, the navigation bar is. So we need to see all of your markup: how the navigation is nested in your html element and what css attributes you added to it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `z-index` greater value for Dialogue then Navbar.

Example if navbar having:

```
z-index:1
```

then use for dialogue

```
z-index:2
```

You should include Html markup and css in your question for better understanding.